# Find same dates in a column and count numbers from there rows together

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-2010

So I have a list with datetimes, mostly there is the same datetimes twice. In the same row of the Dates there  is a number which should be summed up and listed in another sheet.

List example (What I Have now):

```
1   07.09.2015 09:00    118
2   07.09.2015 09:00     31
3   07.09.2015 08:00    148
4   07.09.2015 08:00    56
5   07.09.2015 07:00    128
6   07.09.2015 07:00    49
```

The List could/should goes like this 24 hours a day 365 times a year, actually its just 3 months at the moment.
And I only want to have one Datetime with one number as sum behind.
It also could be posible that there is the same datetime more than twice

So it should look like this in the desired sheet:

```
1   07.09.2015 09:00    149
2   07.09.2015 08:00    204
3   07.09.2015 07:00    177
```

I'm not the best in excel VBA and i only can write a bit of code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pivot table. 
Select all your data. (make sure you have header column and if not add)
select the insert Ribbon and - Insert ->  pivot table. 
Drag your the date to the rpws and the values as sum the values.
You can refrsh the table each time you add data to the data table by choosing Analyze ribbon -> refresh.

If you want to macro this process , the most simple way for starters is to copy a macro. You can view the code later and improve it.

Comment: It should be automatic, is this able trough VBA.

The Idea with the PivotTable is great! thanks

Comment: Of course it can be automated... Yet, it is one time job that could get refreshed by a single button.